# Parse text with powershell and display only what you were searching for

Tags: parsing, powershell, text, pattern-matching, select-string

I'm trying to parse a text file with this format:

```
\\fileshare40\abccheck\logons\ABC64ZXZ.txt:5398:UserID:  abcusernamehere Logged:  09:18:36 2014/03/13
\\fileshare40\abccheck\logons\ABC63BZB.txt:5403:UserID:  abcusernamehere Logged:  01:21:31 2014/03/14
\\fileshare40\abccheck\logons\ABC61ZSF.txt:5408:UserID:  abcusernamehere Logged:  08:22:31 2014/03/17
\\fileshare40\abccheck\logons\ABC62ETB.txt:5413:UserID:  abcusernamehere Logged:  07:58:52 2014/03/18
\\fileshare40\abccheck\logons\ABC60BBB.txt:5418:UserID:  abcusernamehere Logged:  13:11:36 2014/03/19
```

The only thing I need out of here is the machine name (ABC*****).  Later on I'll put it into an array to see what if there are duplicates, but the answer here will get me started on that path.

I've tried this:

```
$abc = select-string -path c:\users\abcusernamehere\desktop\findusermachines.txt -pattern "TCWS....." -allmatches
```

But doing so displays the whole line of text in that file.  How can I break up the line to JUST find and display what I'm searching for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you can use a regex:

```
(get-content c:\users\abcusernamehere\desktop\findusermachines.txt) -replace '.+\\(.+?)\.txt:.+','$1'

ABC64ZXZ
ABC63BZB
ABC61ZSF
ABC62ETB
ABC60BBB
```

There's really no point in using Select-String to search for the lines that have the server names if they all have one.  Just use Get-Content, and run the -replace operator against all the lines.

Comment: Thank you sir.  Any chance you'd know how to get rid of the blank space at the top?

Comment: I put the blank line there to separate the script from the output.  It's not actually part of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a regex match.

```
[regex]::Matches((gc c:\users\abcusernamehere\desktop\findusermachines.txt),"ABC.....")|select -ExpandProperty value
```

That spits back:

```
ABC64ZXZ
ABC63BZB
ABC61ZSF
ABC62ETB
ABC60BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet an other answer :-)

```
${c:\users\abcusernamehere\desktop\findusermachines.txt } | ? { $_ -cmatch "\b(?<MACHINE>ABC.+)\b.txt" }  | % { $Matches['MACHINE'] }
```

ABC64ZXZ
ABC63BZB
ABC61ZSF
ABC62ETB
ABC60BBB